# Routing with polymorphic resources in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic script class like so:

```
Script
  belongs_to :scriptable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

project and testCase are the ones that contain this class. Script also has paperclip and is versionable so basically, i have an existing route already for script:

```
resources :test_cases do
  resources :script do
    resources :script_versions
  end
end
```

That route has existed before but a new feature of our app is to make project scriptable also. Does this mean I have to add the same route to projects like so:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :script do
    resources :script_versions
  end
end
```

What happens if we have other scriptable classes in the future? Do I have to create routes like that every time? It looks so clean yet it doesn't seem DRY to me. polymorphism should be helpig me out here, shouldn't it? Is there a polymorphic way of declaring routes?

Comment: I looking for an answer to the same question. One thing that occurred to me is the polymorphic routes probably want to be "inverted", i.e., /scripts/:id/:parent_model. Working on it. If I figure it out I'll post an answer.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have a similar question and haven't been able to find a DRY way to do it.

Comment: nope not yet. we could put up a bounty if you need. i am not in refactor mode as of the moment, but will be in a couple of weeks hopefully

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple names to `resources` like this

```
resources :test_cases, :projects do
  resources :script do
    resources :script_versions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
[:test_cases, :projects].each do |resource|
    resources resource do
        resources :script do
            resources :script_versions
        end
    end
end
```

Maybe not super elegant, but at least it's DRY